# Use KDtele component to find modem

Tags: c#, dialing

I am using the `KDtele` component to make a dialer program

I use this code to find the modem in my PC and add it to a combo box

```cs
Int32 lNum = 0;
string lName = "";
for (lNum = 0; lNum < axKDPhone1.NumberOfLines - 1; lNum++)
{
    axKDPhone1.GetLineName(lNum, ref lName);
    if (lName != null)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(lName);
    }
}
```

But it does not show my modem.

My modem is a Zoltrix, 56k voice modem.

Comment: Why did you taag this question with three languages. The code looks a bit like C# to me.

Comment: It may only show as the virtual serial port created by the modem.  Is there a COM3 or something in the list?

Comment: i find this. it is work in Win7 but didn't work in Win8